# Mapbox - Custom Marker Popup not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using regular Mapbox GL with React and I am having trouble getting popups to show on custom markers.

I have tried using `addSource` and `addLayer` with a `map.on("click")` event for a popup and it works. But when I try with just a custom marker, the popup created has the content I want to display passed to it, but logs `_container` and `_map` as `undefined`, so it doesn't display.

The code below is within a function component.

The popup function I'm using works for default Mapbox layer items, but not my custom markers.

```js
const popUpRef = useRef(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 15 }))

function createPopUp(currentFeature) {
    const popupNode = document.createElement("div")

    const root = createRoot(popupNode)
    root.render(
        <Popup price={currentFeature.price} />
    )
    popUpRef.current
        .setLngLat(currentFeature.geometry.coordinates)
        .setDOMContent(popupNode)
        .addTo(map.current)
}
```

Default markers that work with the popup:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (!map.current) return; // wait for map to initialize
    map.current.on('load', () => {
        map.current.addSource('data', {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': data
        });
        map.current.addLayer({
            id: 'unclustered-point',
            type: 'circle',
            source: 'data'
        });

        map.current.on("click", e => {
            const features = map.current.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
                layers: ["unclustered-point"]
            });
            if (!features.length) return;
            const clickedPoint = features[0];
            createPopUp(clickedPoint)
        })
    })
},[])
```

The custom markers that I need to work with the popup:

```js
const markerClicked = (feature) => {
    createPopUp(feature) 
};

const Marker = ({ onClick, children, feature }) => {
    const _onClick = () => {
        onClick(feature);
    };

    return (
        <button onClick={_onClick} className="marker">
            {children}
        </button>
    );
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (!map.current) return; // wait for map to initialize
    map.current.on('load', () => {
        data.features.forEach((feature) => {
            const ref = React.createRef();
            ref.current = document.createElement("div");
            const priceJSX = <Typography variant='p'>{feature.price}</Typography>
            const root = createRoot(ref.current)
            root.render(
                <Marker onClick={markerClicked} feature={feature} children={priceJSX} />
            );
            new mapboxgl.Marker(ref.current)
                .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
                .addTo(map.current);
        });
    })
}, [])
```

When I console log the `popUpRef` for the custom markers, I see that `_container` and `_map` are `undefined`, but with the default markers they are defined, even though I'm using the same function.

I even tried passing in the exact feature I get from the `map.on("click")` function to the `onClick` for the custom marker and it still doesn't work.

Can anybody see why I am having trouble getting popups to show on custom markers?

Answer (score 0):

Did someone had a similar issue and found a resolution ?

I had the same problem and I managed to do a **dirty workaround** so I am looking for a cleaner solution.

I also had `_container` and `_map` as `undefined`.
I delayed the `addTo(map)` action. It works but when the popup close, it remains the popup anchor on the map, I don't know why, so have to delete the DOM element manually...

```
useEffect(() => {

 popup
  .setLngLat(coordinates)
  .setDOMContent(popupRef.current);

 // _map & _container : undefined
 // so delay the addTo map
 setTimeout(() => popup.addTo(map), 10);

 return () => {
   ...
   // Clean the remaining anchor 
   document.querySelectorAll('.mapboxgl-popup').forEach(el => el.remove());
 };
}, [])
```

Comment: please just frame this as an answer without the additional question. you can follow the question post to be notified about future answers. answers are not for asking questions or asking for better answers than your own.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35338948)